# How to find the select the whole line for looking for only substring from the line in Python

Tags: python, regex

Example, I have the following lines in file:

> 1. Tom is a guy
> 2. Sara is a woman
> 3. Alex is a guy too

I would like to search for "Sara" but would like to return the whole like

```
   def findLine(self, str):
   ...
```

When I call `findLine("Sara")`, it returns `"2. Sara is a woman"`

How do I accomplish this with Python and Regular Expression (or other non-regular expression method)

Answer (score 5):

I renamed `str` to `content` see senderle's comment

```
def findLine(self, content, search_str):
    for line in content.splitlines()
        if search_str in line:
            return line
    #or something else because the search_str was not found
    return None
```

or if you want a list of all the lines containing sarah

```
def findLine(self, str, search_str):
    return [x for x in str.splitlines() if search_str in x]
```

`search_str` being the string you would like to find.

Comment: But 'str' contains the whole content of the file.

Comment: @Scott: Oh okay. I changed my answer

Comment: Best not to use `str` as a [metasyntactic variable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metasyntactic_variable) since it masks a built-in if taken literally.

Comment: @GWW not to be nit-picky but it should be `"Sara"` ... Personally I'd Pass this in as a parameter.

Comment: Also, seems like this function will only ever search one line from the file. (Note the location of the `return` statement.)

Comment: I know the feeling, believe me :)

Comment: Oh, I didn't know you could use "if search_str in line" like that! Neat.

Answer (score 2):

```
def findline(filename, search_string):
    with open(filename, 'r') as infile:
        for line in infile:
            if search_string in line:
                return line
        else:
            return None
```

Comment: You don't need `'r'` nor the `with` statement. Python's GC closes the file

Comment: @Franklin, `'r'` has _nothing_ to do with `with` or the GC. It determines which mode the file is [opened in](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#open). Mode is always optional; when it is omitted, the `'r'` is assumed. But [explicit is better than implicit](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/).

Comment: Every single person in the whole world knows the default way of opening files is `read`.

Comment: Hah, sender. I don't think Franklin meant to make it seem like the `'r'` and `with` statement were related. Just that neither of them are necessary.

Comment: @Bryce, you're right, I misunderstood Franklin's comment. Thanks!

Comment: @Franklin, sorry to have been brusque, but I still feel that both the `with` statement and the explicit `'r'` are best practices. [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1834556/does-a-file-object-automatically-close-when-its-reference-count-hits-zero) for more info on why it's not good to rely on the GC to close files. More generally, it's not good to rely on the behavior of one implementation -- not all versions of Python behave like cpython.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need RegEx to do this. You could use file.readline() and check if the line contains "Sara". Return the line if it does. Use a for-each loop to check each line in a file.

EDIT:

```
def findlines(filename, searchterm):
    lines = []
    line = filename.readline()

    while line:
        if searchterm in line:
            lines.append(line)

        line = filename.readline()

    return lines
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def find(name)
    for line in open('file.txt'):
        if name in line:
            return line
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you don't need regular expressions:

```
def findline(search_string, file_name, offset=0):
    with open(file_name, 'r') as infile:
        infile.seek(offset)
        for line in infile
            if search_string in line:
               return line
```

(The above is actually just a combination of others' with the addition of file_name as a function param, and offset, meaning you can now traverse the file and get multiple incidences of your sought string).

Answer (score 0):

```
In [6]: lines="""1. Tom is a guy
2. Sara is a woman
3. Alex is a guy too"""

In [10]: lines=lines.splitlines()

In [11]: def findLine(word):
   ....:     return filter(lambda x: word in x,lines)
   ....: 

In [12]: findLine("Alex")
Out[12]: ['3. Alex is a guy too']
```