# how to dump tuples in a list to a text file in Python

Tags: python

I have a list containing many tuples,and stored in `streaming_cfg`

and tried to dump to a text file `DEBUG_STREAMING_CFG_FILE`

however it is an empty file contains nothing.
why ?

```
    debug_file = open(DEBUG_STREAMING_CFG_FILE,'w')
    for lst in streaming_cfg:
        print(lst)
        debug_file.write(' '.join(str(s) for s in lst) + '\n')
    debug_file.close
```

`streaming_cfg`

```
[('0', '0', 'h264', '1/4', '1280x1024', '10', 'vbr', '27', '8m'),
 ('0', '0', 'h264', '1/4', '1280x1024', '10', 'cbr', '6m', 'framerate'),
 ('0', '0', 'h264', '1/4', '1280x1024', '10', 'cbr', '6m', 'imagequality'),
 ('0', '0', 'h264', '1/4', '1280x1024', '10', 'cbr', '8m', 'framerate'),
 ('0', '0', 'h264', '1/4', '1280x1024', '10', 'cbr', '8m', 'imagequality'),
 ('0', '0', 'h264', '1/4', '2560x1920', '8', 'vbr', '27', '8m'),
 ('0', '0', 'h264', '1/4', '2560x1920', '8', 'cbr', '6m', 'framerate'),
 ('0', '0', 'h264', '1/4', '2560x1920', '8', 'cbr', '6m', 'imagequality'),
 ('0', '0', 'h264', '1/4', '2560x1920', '8', 'cbr', '8m', 'framerate'),
 ('0', '0', 'h264', '1/4', '2560x1920', '8', 'cbr', '8m', 'imagequality'),
 ('0', '0', 'mjpeg', '1/2', '1280x1024', '10', 'vbr', '25', '4m'),
 ('0', '0', 'mjpeg', '1/2', '1280x1024', '10', 'cbr', '6m', 'imagequality'),
 ('0', '0', 'mpeg4', '1/2', '1280x1024', '10', 'vbr', '28', '6m'),
 ('0', '0', 'mpeg4', '1/2', '1280x1024', '10', 'cbr', '3m', 'imagequality')]
```

Comment: You need to _call_ the `.close()` method with parentheses: `debug_file.close()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not actually calling `close`, you have merely an expression that evaluates to the callable object.

Replace the last line by

```
debug_file.close()
```

By the way, mistakes like this can be prevented in modern python by use of [context managers](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/):

```
with open(DEBUG_STREAMING_CFG_FILE,'w') as debug_file:
    for lst in streaming_cfg:
        print(lst)
        debug_file.write(' '.join(str(s) for s in lst) + '\n')
```

Comment: Out of curiosity---when the reference counter goes down to zero, or the interpreter shuts down, does the interpreter call `close()` on each `file` object?  (Maybe the OP invoked `exit(2)` to shutdown the interpreter.)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1834556/does-a-file-object-automatically-close-when-its-reference-count-hits-zero

Comment: And if you call `exit` you are at your `libc`'s mercy, I'd guess.

Comment: I take that last one back, to be that destructive (i.e. not call your objects' destructors) you have to use `os._exit`, in which case your open files' buffers won't be flushed.

Comment: @filmore Thanks for your info.  Now I wonder why the OP had the problem just because he failed to properly call `close()`.  It isn't a very productive speculation, though

Comment: Well, it is a productive speculation IMHO ;) My current guess is that the program was still running while the debug file was read.

Comment: I misuse the syntax with ruby and python ~~ sorry

Answer (score 0):

Modern Python:

```
with open(DEBUG_STREAMING_CFG_FILE, "w") as f:
    for lst in streaming_cfg:
        print(' '.join(str(s) for s in lst), file=f)
```

No need to close the opened file.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't call `close()`, but if you use a simpler `with` clause, you don't have to either:

```
with open(DEBUG_STREAMING_CFG_FILE, 'w') as f:
    for lst in streaming_cfg:
        print(lst)
        f.write(' '.join(str(s) for s in lst) + '\n')
```