# How to get information from a file into a tuple

Tags: python

I had to make a file : planets.txt with information about planets. The file looks like this:

```
Planet1 100 200

planet2 200 300

planet3 400 250
```

I have to write a function in python that returns a list with tuples of this information like this :

```
[(100,200),(200,300),(400,250)]
```

The problem is that I don't know how to write this function. Is there anyone who can help me?
Thank you very very much !

Comment: Are the newlines between the "real" lines in `planets.txt` actually there?

Comment: Start reading through [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) and practicing the examples - it will give you ideas. More resources - https://wiki.python.org/moin/BeginnersGuide/Programmers. Have you read/practiced the instructional material you received?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this perhaps?

```
ret = []
lines = open('file.txt').readlines()
for line in lines:
    name, first, second = line.split(' ')
    ret.append((int(first), int(second)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to split each line of your file and append the tuple of the second and the third items of each resulted list to `res` list like below:

```
res = []

with open('planets.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.split():  # I add this because from your input, seems that your file contains some blank lines!
            res.append(tuple(line.split()[1:]))
```

**Output:**

```
>>> res
[('100', '200'), ('200', '300'), ('400', '250')]
```

You can convert each tuple's items to integers like this:

```
>>> [tuple(map(int, item)) for item in res]
[(100, 200), (200, 300), (400, 250)]
```

Comment: There's no need to call `.readlines()`. Just loop `for line in f:` and avoid holding all the lines in memory for no reason when you only need one at a time while parsing (Note: I up-voted anyway, because you were the only answer that actually used `with` appropriately)

Comment: @ShadowRanger Thanks. I know that `readlines()` is not required. I just like explicit things, but I will remove it anyway!

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for compact code.

```
f = open('your_file_path').readlines()
print [tuple(map(int,a.split()[1:])) for a in f if a != '\n']
```

Output:

```
[(100, 200), (200, 300), (400, 250)]
```

Comment: Why don't use the `with` keyword ?

Comment: Good question. Was making it compact. `with` is a better option. I was wondering what will happen to file object since reference count is zero. Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1834556/does-a-file-object-automatically-close-when-its-reference-count-hits-zero