# What happens to file object if opened, iterated and left without reference

Tags: python, python-2.7

If I read my file like this:

```
f = open('path_to_file').readlines()
...more..code...
```

What happens to the file object? When will it close and get garbage collected?

Can anyone explain behind the scenes?

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1834556/does-a-file-object-automatically-close-when-its-reference-count-hits-zero.

Comment: Thanks. It's pretty neat.