# List comprehension with 'with open()' inside

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I am trying to create List comprehension for a list inside this function. I wonder if it is possible to make it cleaner.

```py
def load_list():
    review_list = []
    for counter, entry in enumerate(os.listdir('data/review')):
        if os.path.isfile(os.path.join('data/review', entry)):
            with open(f'data/review/{counter}.txt', encoding='utf-8') as fp:
                review_list.append(fp.read().splitlines())
    return review_list
```

Comment: "with" is not allowed in a list comprehension. I also doubt that the code would become cleaner if it is stuffed in a comprehension.

Comment: Is there a reason you're getting file entries 1) `os.listdir('data/review')`, 2) checking the existence of file entry `os.path.isfile(os.path.join('data/review', entry)`, 3) but opening based upon loop iteration index: `open(f'data/review/{counter}.txt', encoding='utf-8')`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Assumption**

1. There's an error in the post.

This line using counter:

```
with open(f'data/review/{counter}.txt', encoding='utf-8') as fp:
```

Should be using entry:

```
with open(f'data/review/{entry}.txt', encoding='utf-8') as fp:
```

2. We're limiting solution to Python 3.8+

Then we can use the Walrus operator to both simplify original code and make a list comprehension

3. If files are not explicitly closed and are not under a Context manager they will be [Automatically Closed when its Reference Count Hits Zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1834556/does-a-file-object-automatically-close-when-its-reference-count-hits-zero#:~:text=4%20Answers&text=The%20answer%20is%20in%20the,it%20destroys%20file%20object%2C%20but%3A&text=NET%20garbage%20collector%20which%20release,the%20end%20of%20the%20program)

**Walrus Operator in Original Code**

```
import os

def load_list():
    review_list = []
    for entry in os.listdir('data/review'):
        if os.path.isfile(file_path := os.path.join('data/review', entry)):
            with open(file_path, encoding='utf-8') as fp:
                review_list.append(fp.read().splitlines())
    return review_list
```

**Rewriting as List Comprehension**

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join

def load_list():
  return [open(file_path, encoding='utf-8').read().splitlines() for entry in listdir('data/review') if isfile(file_path := join('data/review', entry))]
```

Relying upon assumption 3 to close files in list comprehension.

Answer (score -1):

I came here looking if maybe there's a standard implementation somewhere already, but this can be achieved with a custom inline With:

```py
class With:
  def __init__(self, ctx_mgr):
    self._ctx_mgr = ctx_mgr

  def do(self, fn):
    with self._ctx_mgr as ctx:
      return fn(ctx)

def load_list():
  return [
    With(open(file_path, encoding='utf-8')).do(lambda fh: fh.read().splitlines())
    for entry in listdir('data/review')
    if isfile(file_path := join('data/review', entry))
  ]
```

The simple `With` implementation above can be extended further to handle multiple context managers at once.