# Looping a function using after() method

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, tkinter

I designed a GUI to plot a graph from the text file. However, the plots will not update when I added new points into the text file. I tried using the after() method to keep looping my function to plot the graph but it fails to work. It would not update my plots and it would not even print out 'Updating...' as shown in the code. Would like to know what went wrong and is there a better way to update my plots? Thanks.

```
class Timer: 
def __init__(self, parent): 
    self.parent = parent
    self.time1 = " "
    self.time_label = Label(topFrame, text=self.time1, font = "Helvetica 12 bold")
    self.time_label.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
    self.random_lbl = Label(topFrame, text="Virtual Microgrid", font = "Helvetica 16 bold italic")
    self.random_lbl.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
    self.random_lbl = Label(topFrame, text="GRAPHS", font = "Helvetica 12 bold" )
    self.random_lbl.grid(row = 2, column = 5)
    self.update_clock() 

def update_clock(self): 
    self.time2 = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    self.time1 = self.time2 
    self.time_label.config(text=self.time1)
    self.parent.after(200, self.update_clock) 

def update(self):
    self.animate()
    print("Updating.....")
    self.parent.after(1, self.update)

def animate():
    graph_data = open('example.txt', 'r').read()
    lines = graph_data.split('\n')
    xs = []
    ys = []
    for line in lines:
        if len(line) > 1:
            x,y = line.split(',')
            xs.append(x)
            ys.append(y)

    graph_data = open('example1.txt', 'r').read()
    lines = graph_data.split('\n')
    xs1 = []
    ys1 = []
    for line in lines:
        if len(line) > 1:
            x,y = line.split(',')
            xs1.append(x)
            ys1.append(y)

            graph_data = open('example2.txt', 'r').read()
            lines = graph_data.split('\n')
            xs2 = []
            ys2 = []
            for line in lines:
                if len(line) > 1:
                    x,y = line.split(',')
                    xs2.append(x)
                    ys2.append(y)

            graph_data = open('example3.txt', 'r').read()
            lines = graph_data.split('\n')
            xs3 = []
            ys3 = []
            for line in lines:
                if len(line) > 1:
                    x,y = line.split(',')
                    xs3.append(x)
                    ys3.append(y)

            graph_data = open('example4.txt', 'r').read()
            lines = graph_data.split('\n')
            xs4 = []
            ys4 = []
            for line in lines:
                if len(line) > 1:
                    x,y = line.split(',')
                    xs4.append(x)
                    ys4.append(y)

            fig = Figure(figsize=(13,3.25))
            a = fig.add_subplot(111)
            a.plot(xs,ys,color='red')
            a.plot(xs1,ys1,color='blue')
            a.plot(xs4,ys4,color='black')

            a.set_title ("SOURCE", fontsize=8)
            a.set_ylabel("Voltage/V", fontsize=8)
            a.set_xlabel("Time/s", fontsize=8)
            a.grid()

            fig5 = Figure(figsize=(13,3.25))
            f = fig5.add_subplot(111)
            f.plot(xs2,ys2,color='red')
            f.plot(xs3,ys3,color='blue')


            f.set_title ("LOAD", fontsize=8)
            f.set_ylabel("Voltage/V", fontsize=8)
            f.set_xlabel("Time/s", fontsize=8)
            f.grid()

            canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=rightFrame)
            canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(row = 2, column = 1, sticky = "nswe")
            canvas.draw()

            canvas5 = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig5, master=rightFrame)
            canvas5.get_tk_widget().grid(row = 3, column = 1, sticky = "nswe")
            canvas5.draw()
```

Comment: You never actually call the `update` function. However, mind that doing so will result in a problem: For each update you create two completely new figures. Instead you should create the figures and att them to the canvas *outside*  of your updating function.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that  you close the file every time after  you get all the data.
Look at following

[Is close() necessary when using iterator on a Python file object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832528/is-close-necessary-when-using-iterator-on-a-python-file-object)