# How to SPLIT the data in one column and store the values in new column in python3.x csv module functionalities

Tags: python-3.x, csv, multiple-columns

I'm trying to split the data existing in one column and store that into a new Column

```
**Inputdata.csv**
Braund, Mr. Owen Harris ,1
Heikkinen, Miss. Laina ,0
Allen, Mr. William Henry ,0
**Expecting_output.csv**
Braund,Owen Harris ,1,Mr
Heikkinen,Laina ,0,Miss
Allen,William Henry ,0,Mr
```

I have tried and got the Find and replace functionality but unable to code the Find and store it into new column

```
import csv
print(dir(csv))
filename = "H:\\FairDealCustomerData.csv"
csvout = "H:\\FairDealCustomerDataOUT.csv"
with open(filename,"r",newline='') as file:
     file = ''.join([i for i in file]).replace("Mr.", "")
     file = ''.join([i for i in file]).replace("Miss.", "")
     file = ''.join([i for i in file]).replace("Mrs.", "")
with open(csvout,"w",newline='') as outfile:
     outfile.writelines(file)
     outfile.close()

Inputdata.csv
Braund, Mr. Owen Harris ,1
Heikkinen, Miss. Laina ,0
Allen, Mr. William Henry ,0
 Expecting_output.csv
Braund,Owen Harris ,1,Mr
Heikkinen,Laina ,0,Miss
Allen,William Henry ,0,Mr
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, same output as expect you.

```py
import csv

filename = "H:\\FairDealCustomerData.csv"
csvout = "H:\\FairDealCustomerDataOUT.csv"

with open(filename, 'r', newline='') as read_file:
    readCSV = csv.reader(read_file, delimiter=',')
    with open(csvout, 'w', newline='') as write_file:
        writer = csv.writer(write_file)
        for row in readCSV:
            writer.writerow([row[0], row[1].split('.')[1].strip() + ' ', row[2], row[1].split('.')[0].strip()])
```

Answer (score 0):

Using regular expressions to extract the different groups and re-order them as desired.

```py
import re
new_lines = []
with open('inputdata.txt', 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        regex = re.compile(r'(\w+),\s?(Mr.|Miss.|Mrs.)\s(\w+\s?\w*\s),([01])')
        new_line = regex.findall(line)[0]
        print(f"{new_line[0]},{new_line[2]},{new_line[3]},{new_line[1]}")
```

Result:

```py
Braund,Owen Harris ,1,Mr.
Heikkinen,Laina ,0,Miss.
Allen,William Henry ,0,Mr.
```

Answer (score 0):

Hooray I got it thanks @Kushan Gunasekera

```
import csv
filename = "F:\\FairDealCustomerData.csv"
csvout = "F:\\FairDealCustomerDataout.csv"
with open(filename,'r',newline='') as read_file:
    readCSV = csv.reader(read_file, delimiter=',')
    with open(csvout,"w",newline='') as write_file:
        writer = csv.writer(write_file)
        for row in readCSV:
            writer.writerow([row[0], row[1].split('.')[1].strip() + ' ', row[2], 
            row[1].split('.')[0].strip()])
write_file.close()

ALERT:please do care about with and for functionalities other wise we will get 
 ValueError: I/O operation on closed file
```

Comment: he he your're welcome @prasanthG, and one more you don't need to close in when you open with `with` statements. Please check these questions, [Is explicitly closing files important?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7395542/6194097), [Is close necessary when using iterator on a Python file object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1832528/6194097) and [Why should I close files in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25070854/6194097). Got it bro? So you don't need to close it.