# Print results to .txt

Tags: python

What is the best way to print the results of this math calculation to a document like .txt?
What am i doing wrong?

```
def divide(x, y):
    return x / y

print("Menu.")
print("1.Offers")

while True:
    choice = input("Choose1(1): ")

    if choice in ('1'):
        num1 = float(input("Price: "))
        num2 = float(input("Surcharge: "))

        if choice == '1':
            print(num1, "/", num2, "==", divide(num1, num2))
        break
    else:
        print("Invalid Input")
```

Comment: I edited the question to fix the code formatting, including the indenting. Just mentioning on the off chance I got it wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply do not write in a file.

Below the syntax to save your result.

```
def divide(x, y):
  return x / y

print("Menu.")
print("1.Offers")

while True:

  choice = input("Choose1(1): ")

  if choice in ('1'):
    num1 = float(input("Price: "))
    num2 = float(input("Surcharge: "))

    if choice == '1':
        print(str(num1)+"/"+str(num2)+"="+str(divide(num1, num2)))
        
        with open("output.txt", "w") as msg:
            msg.write(str(num1)+"/"+str(num2)+"="+str(divide(num1, num2)))
            msg.close()
    break
  else:
    print("Invalid Input")
```

Comment: Btw you don't need the `msg.close()` when using `with open(...) as msg:` [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832528/is-close-necessary-when-using-iterator-on-a-python-file-object)

Comment: Thanks. You have a ref/link for that? I confess I tend to clean things up when I am not sure ;)

Comment: @Synthase Ref: [Reading and Writing Files - Python Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files): *"It is good practice to use the [`with`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#with) keyword when dealing with file objects. The advantage is that the file is properly closed after its suite finishes, even if an exception is raised at some point."*

Comment: If you use `print(file=msg)`, you don't need to do manual string conversion and joining. `print(num1, "/", num2, "==", divide(num1, num2), file=msg)`

Comment: Thank you Synthase!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
with open("f.txt", 'w') as f:
    f.write(str(num1)+"/"+str(num2)+"="+str(divide(num1, num2)))
```