# Does open('file.txt','r') automatically close file in python

Tags: python, file-handling

I have a code using which i am getting count from file

**Cases:**

```
1. ignore blank lines
2. ignore empty lines 
3. ignore spaces
4. ignore tabs
```

The code works fine it gives proper count

```
sum(1 for i in open('/path/ABC.txt',"r").readlines() if i.strip())
```

Their is no `close` given in code , Does once it is open the python automatically closes the file ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is close() necessary when using iterator on a Python file object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832528/is-close-necessary-when-using-iterator-on-a-python-file-object)

Comment: Enable warnings with: `import warnings; warnings.simplefilter('default')` - Python will tell you if you missed closing a file.

Comment: @PiotrPraszmo  : Thanks by importing warnings it showed me : `ResourceWarning : unclosed file`

Answer (score 1):

No, the file will not be closed in this case.

*See the example below*

> **f.closed** - Returns True if file is closed else False

```
# Your case
f1 = open('text.txt', 'r')
sum(1 for i in f1.readlines() if i.strip())
print(f1.closed)

# Using Context Manager
f2 = open('text.txt', 'r')
with f2:
    sum(1 for i in f2.readlines() if i.strip())
print(f2.closed)
```

```
False
True
```

You can see that in the first case, the file is NOT closed where as in the second case, it is closed. So always use a context manager when reading & writing files.

From the [Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)

> It is good practice to use the with keyword when dealing with file objects. The advantage is that the file is properly closed after its suite finishes, even if an exception is raised at some point.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of your script all handlers will be closed. It doesn't matter for a
read-only file. This can become hazardous for files opened for writing.
The proper way is to use the context manager because at the end of the scope, the file will be properly closed.

```
with open('/path/ABC.txt',"r") as fp:
    sum(1 for i in fp.readlines() if i.strip())
```

Answer (score 0):

Python automatically gets rid of the file during the garbage collection or at the end of the program which means you don't have to close it.

But I would use the "with" keyword where gives a better syntax and exceptions handling as well as closes the file at the end of it.

```
with open('/path/ABC.txt',"r") as f: 
    #The rest of the code
```