# python: alternatives for with statement

Tags: python, with-statement

I use with statement in python script:

```
ReadFile = open(file, "r")
                with ReadFile as f:  
                    for line in f:
                        print line
```

I use python 2.5, but this script could be used in older python versions. And in those versions there is error:

```
with ReadFile as f:
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

could someone advise me some alternatives for with statement in python for versions earlier that 2.5?

Comment: The suggested answer is for python 2.5, however the OP is asking a solution for the versions earlier than 2.5.

Comment: You are right, I use `from __future__ import with_statement` for python 2.5, but it doesn't work for earliest versions

Comment: try, except and finally can be used to match the with statement. I'm not sure if there is a better solution.

Comment: The second answer shows you exactly what to do: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7919428/3001761