# Yield & closing file objects properly

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have the following class:

```
class JsonIterator(object):
    def __init__(self,folder):
        self.root = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), folder)
        self.fis = [fi for fi in os.listdir(folder) if "lyrics" in fi]

    def __iter__(self):
        i = 0
        with open(os.path.join(self.root,self.fis[i])) as f:
            yield json.load(f)
        i += 1
```

It's not working how I want it to--it seems not to get beyond the first file. I've tried

```
def __iter__(self):
    i = 0
    f = open(os.path.join(self.root, self.fis[i]))
    js = json.load(f)
    f.close()
    yield js
    i += 1
```

But either way, `len(list(JsonIterator("path/to/myfolder")))` gives me `1`, and I know for a fact that there is more than one file in the folder. The alternative, of course, would be something like

```
def __iter__(self):
    i = 0
    yield json.load(open(os.path.join(self.root, self.fis[i])))
    i += 1
```

but all those dangling open files suck up so much memory my process gets killed.

So what should I do? I thought about writing some kind of decorator, but I don't really understand how those work, or even if it'd solve my problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to loop over the filenames in `self.fis`:

```
class JsonIterator(object):
    def __init__(self,folder):
        self.root = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), folder)
        self.fis = [fi for fi in os.listdir(folder) if "lyrics" in fi]

    def __iter__(self):
        for fi in self.fis:
            with open(os.path.join(self.root, fi)) as f:
                obj = json.load(f)
            yield obj
```

Comment: I think I would store the result of `json.load()` in a variable, and yield it from outside the context manager, so that the file is closed before the function pauses;  otherwise, this is the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the other answers, you need to iterate over your list of files inside of `__iter__()`.  Here is an equivalent alternative that uses a generator expression to do the same thing:

```
def __iter__(self):
    return (json.load(open(os.path.join(self.root, fi))) for fi in self.fis)
```

[The files will be closed automatically when they are garbage collected](https://stackoverflow.com/a/575320/505154), assuming you are using CPython.

Comment: files will be closed automatically when they are garbage collected in all python implementations I'm aware of. Only in CPython, which uses reference counting, will the be collected *immediately*, instead of, say, on program exit, or when the program is experiencing load at a later time.