# Creating a dictionary from a .txt file using courses

Tags: python

Write a program to create a dictionary that has the key-value pairs from the file 
"CourseInstructor.txt"
I started to create a dictionary using the txt, file but receive the following error:

```
Course=("CourseInstructor.txt",'r')
for line in Course:
    key,val = line.split(" ")
    Inst[key] = val
Course.close()
```

ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

Comment: Can u post your file as well.?

Comment: You never opened the file. You missed `open` in front of `("CourseInstructor.txt",'r')`.

Comment: I guess your file `CourseInstructor.txt` don't contain enough data.

Answer (score 3):

You should do something like this:

```
Inst = dict()
with open("CourseInstructor.txt",'r') as Course:
    for line in Course:
        key,val = line.rstrip("\n").split(" ")
        Inst[key] = val
```

the best way to open files is `with`, it will close file after.
the `rstrip("\n")` will remove `\n` from end of each line.
one more thing that you should know is your input file(`CourseInstructor.txt`) should be like this:

```
key1 value1
key2 value2
key3 value3
```

If your file dose not contain new lines, use this:

```
your_string = your_string.split(" ")
keys = [i for i in your_string[::2]]
values = [i for i in your_string[1::2]]
final_dict = {keys[i]:values[i] for i in range(len(values)) }
```

Comment: I tried that and it is still giving me the same error :ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

Comment: For this line of code: key,val = line.rstrip("\n").split(" ")

Comment: please post you file content. @Nat

Comment: CIS2200 Izen
CIS3100 Ennoure
CIS3120 Kumar
CIS3400 Ferns
CIS3750 Gubernat
CIS3920 Cai
CIS4100 Friedman
CIS4110 Finnegan
CIS4160 Craig
CIS4400 Holowczak
CIS4800 Finnegan
CIS5800 Brown
CIS9340 Kline
CIS9440 Holowczak
CIS9480 Bianco
CIS9490 Kiris
CIS9557 Kumar
CIS9660 Gao

Comment: but it isn't all in one line

Comment: it looks like what you posted it anove key1 value1 etc

Comment: @Nat i updated my answer if all of values are in one line.

Answer (score 0):

If your file looks like this:

```
key1 value1
key2 value2
key3 value3
```

you can try:

```
print({line.split()[0]:line.split()[1] for line in open('file','r')})
```

Output:

```
{'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2', 'key3': 'value3'}
```

File  will eventually be closed when the file object is garbage collected. [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/575278/how-does-python-close-files-that-have-been-gced) for more info.